# Modify Control from Background Worker. Does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I've made a background worker within my window and it works great.  The code is starting to get long so I decided to create a worker class and put all my logic in there.  However, when I do that I no longer am able to modify the value of my progress bar.

I get a "does not exist in current context."  I wonder if this has something to do with the fact that this is on a separate thread??  I researched that too and I didn't find an explanation or solution.

I made my progress bar in the XAML public but that made no difference.

Here is my main window code.  No problems here that I can see.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Market.BI.Workers;

namespace Market
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            File_Worker my_worker = new File_Worker();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my class.  This is where I can't access the progress bar control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Market.BI.Workers
{
    class File_Worker
    {
        private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {   
            Stuff
        }
        void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Stuff
        }
        void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Stuff
        }

        //Method
        public File_Worker()
        {
            worker.DoWork               += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
            worker.ProgressChanged      += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Worker_ProgressChanged);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted   += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            fileProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Also: How is the stack trace, how is the full exception? (`x.ToString()`).

Comment: @keim - it's the last line.  fileProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the progress bar exists in your `MainWindow` but not in the `File_Worker`.

When all the worker's code was inside the MainWindow, it could access the progress bar just easily. But the `File_Worker` doesn't know, where to get the progress bar from.

---

The easiest solution would be to pass all the needed UI objects (e. g., the progress bar) to the worker class in its constructor, store the said objects in field(s) and access them wherever needed.

Comment: I tried that earlier.  public File_Worker(object fileProgressBar)   The problem is there are no properties for that object.   Or is using object the wrong type?

Comment: @Pirate: Why `object` and not `ProgressBar`?

Comment: Worked like a charm!   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

Send reference of your MainWindow to the File_Worker Class

```
// in MainWindow
File_Worker my_worker = new File_Worker(this);

// in File_Worker Class
class File_Worker
{
    private MainWindow _mainWin;
    Public File_Worker(MainWindow senderClass) 
    {
        _mainWin = senderClass;
    }
```

Make these changes to Worker_DoWork, to see progress

```
void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker backGroundWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
```

Make these changes to Worker_ProgressChanged, to update the UI

```
void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{   
    _mainWin.progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```